# SBJsonParser to store response from server in custom class

Tags: mysql, ios, arrays, json, class

I have a mySQL database and a php script which returns the contents of a table from said database. I have this data as a string and am able to put it into an array, but I'm not too sure how I'd go about putting it into a custom NSObject class. Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string is an array of JSON objects you can use the SBJsonParser method `objectWithString:` which will return an NSArray of NSDictionary objects.  Then you can loop though your array and create a custom object from each element in the array.  Use the NSDictionary method `objectForKey:` to extract each value.

```
SBJsonParser *json = [[SBJsonParser new] autorelease];
NSError *jsonError = nil;
NSArray *parsedJSON = [json objectWithString:response error:&jsonError];            

// this example just creates a custom object from the first element in the array
NSDictionary dictionary = [parsedJSON objectAtIndex:0]           
CustomObject *myCustomObject = [[CustomObject alloc] init];
myCustomObject.firstname = [dictionary objectForKey:@"firstname"];
myCustomObject.lastname = [dictionary objectForKey:@"lastname"];
```

Comment: Thanks, it's so simple! So to loop through the table, I simply place the code in a for loop, and change 0 to i?

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do it just for the first row of the table but I am having problems. When I am running `NSLog(@"EVENT NAME: %@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"eventName"]);`, I get back (null). I am getting the request Asynchronously so thought it may have not had time to get the data. If I change this to Synchronous, the app crashes with `[__NSCFDictionary objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6b1f8b0'`. Any ideas?

Comment: What is the structure of the JSON you are getting?  If the JSON string is not an array (for example, if the array is wrapped in a a single top-level node such as 'events') then the SBJsonParse method `objectWithString:` will instead return an NSDictionary object from which you'll first need to extract the array.

Comment: This is the response of the server: `{"eventsInfo":[{"eventID":"4","eventName":"Pop Tarts","eventAddress":"Students Union, Sheffield","eventPrice":"5","eventTime":"21:00:00","eventRating":"3","eventLogo":null},{"eventID":"5","eventName":"Space","eventAddress":"Octagon, SU, Sheffield","eventPrice":"4","eventTime":"21:00:00","eventRating":"5","eventLogo":null}]}`

Comment: Ah, as I thought.  So you can do:

`NSArray *parsedJSON = [(NSDictionary*)[json objectWithString:response error:&jsonError] objectForKey:@"eventsInfo"];`

Comment: I have used that instead, but I am still getting Null as the response. Here is the code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/mfGGEGTV

Comment: Solved: I had to use Synchronous instead of Asynchronous - that's annoying.

Comment: When you use [parser objectWithString:jsonData error:&jsonError] you need to set the first argument (objectWithString) to the JSON string you you get from your call to `getTableInfo getDataFromTable:`

Comment: Yeah, it is, it's just stored in a variable called jsonData. Is there any way I can do this ASynchcronously?

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work asynchronously.  Just put your SBJsonParser code in the delegate callback function.

Comment: It doesn't work because what I am trying to do is populate a tableview. So if I did it this way (and not in `viewWillLoad`), the data doesn't show up as the tableview has already loaded. Unless there is a refresh view method I could call? I've had a look around for one without any luck.

Comment: You can call `reloadData` on the tableView, however the catch is that you need to use `performSelectorOnMainThread:` because all UI operations need to be done on the main thread, and by doing your parsing asynchronously you have spawned a new thread.  So something like the following:

    `[[self tableView] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) 
                                       withObject:nil 
                                    waitUntilDone:NO];`

Comment: Tried that, and still nothing. With Asynchronous, it just returns null each time.